# handlebars does not render my moongose array

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, backend, express-handlebars

so I'm using moongose, handlebars and express, I'm trying to render an array of products from moongose in handlebars, in an instance, I received this error:

```
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "title" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
```

but now I just don't get any error in console.

this is my app.js (I erased the password in mongoose.connect)

```
    import express from "express"
import handlebars from "express-handlebars"
import viewsRouter from "./routes/views.routers.js"

import { Server } from "socket.io"
import { productService } from "./services/product.service.js"
import mongoose from "mongoose"


mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://manumore42:password@cluster0.gfxayke.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")



const productsList = await productService.getProducts()
const app = express()

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const webServer = app.listen(4040,()=>{console.log("listening on port 4040...")})
const io = new Server(webServer)



app.engine('handlebars',handlebars.engine())
app.set('views', "views/")
app.set('view engine' , 'handlebars')
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('/',viewsRouter)



io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    console.log('cliente conectado')
    socket.emit('prodsList' , productsList)
    socket.on('message', data=>{
        console.log(data)
    })

    socket.on('deleteProd',async (id)=>{
        await productService.deleteProduct(id)
    })

    socket.on('newProduct' , async (prod)=> {
        await productService.addProduct(prod)
    })
})
```

this is my viewsRouter

```
               import { Router } from "express"
import { productService } from "../services/product.service.js"

const router = Router()

router.get("/",async(req,res)=>{
    const products = await productService.getProducts()
    res.render('home',{products})
})

router.get("/realtimeproducts",(req,res)=>{
    res.render('realTimeProducts',{})
})

router.use('/products', async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const products = await productService.getProducts()
        res.render('products',{products})
    } catch(err){
        res.send(err)
    }
      

})

export default router
```

the ones with endpoint "/" and "realTimeProducts" render properly but they work differently,the "/products" one is failing to render

and this is my products.handlebars

```
    <h1>
    Productos:
</h1>
<div id="productsList">
    {{#each products}}

    <div class="secondaryDiv">
        <h2>producto:</h2>
        <p>{{this.title}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="secondaryDiv">
        <h2>precio:</h2>
        <p>{{this.price}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="secondaryDiv">
        <h2>descripcion:</h2>
        <p>{{this.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="secondaryDiv">
        <h2>stock disponible:</h2>
        <p>{{this.stock}}</p>
    </div>

    {{/each}}
</div>
```

- update *

I tried to do a console.log of products, and throws this:

```
 const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `products.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\CoderHouse\BackEnd\desafios modulo 2\entregable 6\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

Node.js v18.13.0
```